# How to use cmake to compile autoconf project?

Tags: cmake, autoconf

I'm using cmake to build my project, and I want it to integrate with a third party library called Project_A that using autoconf to generate make, how to write the CMakeLists.txt to build the Project_A and my project together?

Thanks!

Comment: Project_A is a dependency.  Install it.  Require it.  Why would you want to integrate it into your project at the source level?

Comment: @WilliamPursell we need to modify the dependency project's code, we want Project_A's code to be part of my project

Comment: If you are modifying Project_A, then do so, but there's no need to incorporate it into your tree.  Modify it, install the modified version, and use it!  If necessary, rename it and fork it, but in the long run maintenance is much more difficult if you integrate the library into your code base.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I want to ship my project as a standalone package without external dependency, so that's why I want to compile with the source, maybe the alternative way is to do a static link

Answer (score 0):

I think using the ExternalProject module in CMake would be the best solution. See [here](http://www.kitware.com/media/html/BuildingExternalProjectsWithCMake2.8.html) for a good introduction to the api.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to do lexical code reuse (ie, copy-n-paste the code rather then relying on a dependency), then don't stop half way.  By using the external code in this way, you are essentially claiming ownership of it for the purpose of your project, so there is no need to keep the autotool build.  Just pull the code out and build it via cmake.  Don't bother trying to create a hybrid build.

Comment: @ruipacheco Yes, it will.  If you are copying the code into your tree, it is completely irrelevant if your project is a library.